# Vagrant 1.5 share feature & Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, vagrant

I have successfully upgraded to Vagrant 1.5 but when I have made a share link like so: http://hard-sloth-1476.vagrantshare.com/ I just get the Apache landing page and not my site. The site is built with Laravel and when I navigate locally to the VM http://192.168.33.11.xip.io it all works fine, but i just get this page:

[image]

When using vagrant share

So how does one fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you will need to create a virtual host on vagrant for the vagrant share generated url.

Comment: How would one do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your apache/nginx config doesn't resolve that url to your server. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

You need to specify that your new vagrant share url points to your virtual host on the web server.